# Error in my XAML Project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I made a Windows app and done changes to it but when I start debug(run) the app, following error occurred can someone help please.

> Error 1   Could not write to output file 'c:\Users\MuhammadAshbal\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Hotel\Hotel\obj\Debug\intermediatexaml\Hotel.exe' -- 'Access is denied. ' c:\users\muhammadashbal\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Hotel\Hotel\CSC   Hotel

I tried many ways but in vain.

Comment: Probably, exe file in using or opened.
To check  if it opened: use Task Manager

Comment: Try **Clean Solution**, then **Build Solution**. You probably have the file in use somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Try below:

a) Open VS as administrator and then build and run.

b) open project folder, check property of folder, un-check read only option and then try building solution.